# Query/Count for a field in Elasticsearch not present in index mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have field (***"brandTag"***) in ElasticSearch. Unfortunately, its, added after ES index is created (the initial index mapping does not have this field)

How do I `_search/_count` docs which contains this ***"brandTag"*** field only?

Simply querying like following ***do not*** work:

```
GET my-index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "brandTag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any way I can query this without any changes to indices (reindex, etc.)?

---

PS:

- If it matters, ***brandTag*** is an array of objects `{ "value":, "owner":, "createdby":, "comment": }`
- I would need this for .NET (Nest), but I can manage that if I get something working using curl/kabana.
- Elasticsearch Ver: 6.2

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? does it return the wrong value?
this query should work. you dont need to use bool filter, only query-exists works.

Comment: It turns out my "brandTag" is not indexed so I don't get correct result ,hence the "doesn't work" part.

Answer (score 0):

[_count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-count.html) exist in elasticsearch v6, but you should define the document type because you are using elasticsearch v6.

There are two methods to achieve this.

**1- _count API (_doc added)**

```
GET my-index/_doc/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "brandTag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2- track total hits in the query body (it looks like it's available for Elasticsearch v7 and onwards)**

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "match" : {
      "user.id" : "elkbee"
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits

Comment: It turns out my "brandTag"  field is not indexed so cannot use direct query

Comment: hmm, do you mean the brandTag field has "index": false? settings